# KVM - My switch can manage ACLs, when I create bridged VMs (KVM), does the switch see them as “ports”?

Tags: networking, security, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, access-control-list

My Cisco Switch has some nifty L3 features like ACLs

I will have one of my physical hosts running KVM with multiple VMs. They are networked in bridged mode. I'm not overly familiar, but want to prevent "peer to peer" access between VMs. Seems like a perfect use of ACLs.

However, considering guest-A and guest-B are on the same physical host, I am curious as to whether they will ever get to the switch if trying to access each other...

**Questions**

1. Do bridged-configured VMs trying to talk to each other reach the physical switch, or reside within the host they are running on?
2. If VM-VM communication will be intercepted by the host, is the IPTables on the host the best way to prevent communication?

Answer (score 0):

1/ no, vm to vm bridged communications remains inside the host.

2/ I think you should consider using macvlan VEPA mode instead of bridged mode if you want your switch to be able to apply acls. [more details here https://hicu.be/bridge-vs-macvlan]